# Problem of titles with single quotation mark on about page

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, profile-page, special-characters

I answered a question on Stackoverflow which seems normal on post.

- [Does it matter performance wise if there is an `else` after the first `return`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102954/does-it-matter-performance-wise-if-there-is-an-else-after-the-first-return)

When I add it to about page in my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul), questions title seems broken because of single quotation mark. [**``**]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not single quotation marks, but backticks, so the Markdown parser thinks you're closing (and then opening a new) `<code>` blocks as you've seemingly wrapped the link text as such. You can just escape them:

```
[``Does it matter performance wise if there is an `else` after the first `return`?``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102954/does-it-matter-performance-wise-if-there-is-an-else-after-the-first-return)
```

produces

[`` Does it matter performance wise if there is an `else` after the first `return`? ``](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102954/does-it-matter-performance-wise-if-there-is-an-else-after-the-first-return)

Comment: @Manishearth: Why is it a bug?

Comment: @TimStone: Nvm, misunderstood your answer.